Creation and annihilation operators in complex projective space
Note 1: The Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ of a quantum system cannot possibly be the genuine space of states in quantum mechanics. In particular, $\vec{0} \in \mathcal{H}$, which is not a valid state. Hence, to call $\mathcal{H}$ the space of states would be to call $\vec{0}$ a state, which as stated above is not a valid state.
Note 2: Even in "conventional" quantum mechanics, the space of states is not a vector space. It is the set of trace-class, positive-definite, trace-one operators over Hilbert space, denoted $\overline{\mathcal{B}}^+(\mathcal{H})$. Also known as density operators.
(At the least) Finite dimensional quantum mechanics formally has $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ as the raw space of states. To be explicit, $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ corresponds to the rays in $\mathbb{C}^n$. There does not exist an additive identity element (a zero element) of $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$. However, naively creation and annihilation operators require the notion of an additive identity element as evidenced by the expression
$$\hat{a} \lvert 0 \rangle = 0 \text{ (the zero vector)}$$
where $\hat{a}: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$. Without access to such an additive identity element, how does one talk about creation and annihilation operators $\hat{a}: \mathbb{C}P^{n-1} \to \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$?

This question is similar to: Hilbert space vs. Projective Hilbert space. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@hft It is unclear to me how the question I asked (specifically about what C/A operators look like in complex projective space) has anything to do with a broad question about what is the complex projective space associated with a Hilbert space.

You seem to be complaining that the zero vector is not a ray.

I'm not sure how this is a complaint. It is an observation that naively the annihilation operator (or any relation to it) cannot be defined as a map from the space of states into the space of states in quantum mechanics. The Hilbert space is by definition not the space of states because the zero vector is not a state. @hft

You already have received an answer to your question. In that answer the "space of states" is the Hilbert space. I guess you will have to wait for another answer, since I'm not sure what you continue to dispute here.

I am not sure what is unclear by my comment above. Under no reasonable definition can the Hilbert space be called the space of states. Unless you would like to call $\vec{0}$ a state. @hft

Good luck with all that...

@SillyGoose the fact that you have an element in ${\cal H}$ which is not a state doen't mean you can dispense with ${\cal H}$. Quantum Mechanics relies on the vector space structure of ${\cal H}$. You cannot reformulate it purely in terms of some projective space without the underlying Hilbert space

The postulates of Quantum Mechanics demand that there be a Hilbert space of states ${\cal H}$. States are then unit rays on ${\cal H}$, so we may take $$\mathscr{S} = \{[\Psi] : \Psi\in \mathcal{H}, \Psi \sim \lambda \Psi, \lambda\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}, |\Psi|=1\}.$$
For ${\cal H}=\mathbb{C}^n$ this is indeed a subspace of $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ (note that there is the unit ray condition: states should be normalized due to the probabilistic interpretation).
Now, the equation $a_p|0\rangle=0$ is not an equation in $\mathscr{S}$, rather it's an equation in ${\cal H}$. So while it is true that the states are really unit rays and therefore elements of ${\mathscr{S}}$, you cannot simply dispense with ${\cal H}$ and work just with $\mathscr{S}$. In fact, most of the time we just work in ${\cal H}$ with normalized states $|\Psi|=1$ and recall that they are defined up to a global phase because of the equivalence relation.

I understand that out of convenience we work in $\mathcal{H}$. However, for $\mathscr{S}$ to deserve the name space of states, we should not have to rely on the auxiliary space $\mathcal{H}$.

You misunderstood, it is not that we work in ${\cal H}$ for convenience. $\mathscr{S}$ just appears because there is this phase redundancy when working with elements of ${\cal H}$ and then we might group the states into equivalence classes since some of them give rise to the same Physics in the end. But ${\cal H}$ is fundamental: the notion of superposition of states is central to QM: you need a vector space structure for that and $\mathscr{S}$ is not a vector space ($\mathbb{CP}^1\simeq S^2$ for example)

But the vector space structure is, strictly speaking, an incorrect structure for the space of quantum states. Any vector space contains $\vec{0}$ which is itself not a state (by the usual notion of a state in quantum mechanics).

It is not the incorrect structure. It is the structure that is postulated in the postulates of quantum mechanics and which is central to quantum theory. You need a vector space structure to have superposition of states (which is one of the central features of QM), to have linear hermitian operators (which are the observables) and to get entanglement out of the tensor product structure. You seem to be disputing the postulates of QM, but the point is that they are the way they are to give you a framework compatible with what has been observed about quantum phenomena.

But a vector space structure is simply not necessary. My point is the inclusion of the zero vector to make the structure a vector space is purely out of convenience. I am certain I can construct a mathematical structure which includes (i) superposition of states and (ii) excludes the zero vector.

I'm sorry to disagree, a vector space structure is necessary for QM. You simply cannot dispense with ${\cal H}$ and recover all of quantum mechanics from some $\mathbb{CP}^n$. I repeat what I said, the vector space structure is necessary to get stuff like superpositions, entanglement, etc, which are all observed phenomena

See also Valter Moretti's answer (perhaps opinion as evidenced by the contention here...) in support of my claim: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/819921/is-the-zero-vector-necessary-to-do-quantum-mechanics.

Even for normal quantum mechanics, the Hilbert space is not really the privileged structure to be called space of states. We would have the subset of positive-definite trace-one operators on the Banach space of trace-class linear operators over Hilbert space. In this case we again do not have a vector space structure.

I understand the intuition that “since states are elements of the projective space of a Hilbert space there must be a way to do all QM with just the projective space”, but I think this is more like an intuition than a precise statement in itself. You would need to come up with some concrete and mathematically precise construction showing how you are going to reproduce state superposition, entanglement, commutation relations, etc, without a vector space structure. You are essentially looking for an alternative axiomatization of QM without vector spaces, and personally I don't believe it exists.

Remember that state vectors on the Hilbert space are defined modulo a phase and a norm. The normalization postulate can be dropped as long as you define $$ \langle \hat{O} \rangle = \frac{\langle \psi | \hat{O} | \psi \rangle}{\langle \psi|\psi \rangle} $$ (this implies that the whole distribution is normalized since is given by the expectation values on the projectors). So the phase space is by definition necessarily $\mathcal{P(H)}$, whether we like it or not.  
Now, regarding your objection, you are implicitly assuming that the operators must be defined on $\mathcal{P(H)}$, which is not necessary. As long as you can compute the distributions, you're good. In order to find a distribution, you don't need to actually apply the operator, you just need the expectation values of projectors, which are well-defined scalar functions on our phase space, being representative-independent.  
Wait, but what about the Schrodinger equation? You need to apply the Hamiltonian there! 
Well, not necessarily. $\mathcal{P(H)}$ has a natural Kahler structure, which is essentially the complex version of symplectic geometry (classical Hamiltonian mechanics). Turns out that you can use the same machinery you use in the classical case, i.e. defining a Hamiltonian vector field s.t.
$$ \Omega(\cdot, X_H) = dH$$
where $\Omega$ is the natural symplectic form and $H$ is the expectation value of the Hamiltonian operator (again a well-defined scalar on $\mathcal{P(H)}$).  You can then explicitly show, with some basic calculation, that the Schrodinger equation is a particular case where you choose your representatives to be normalized.
This is called the geometrical formulation of quantum mechanics.

Do you have a suggested reference?

This book contains a physicist-friendly introduction to the subject. For a more mature (and rigorous) treatment there is this paper. The Schrodinger equation is proven on H instead of P(H) but you can easily generalize it using arbitrary lifts
